# Unable to left-align iCheck checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox, icheck

I'm trying to left-align an iCheck checkbox, but for some reason, no matter what I do, I just can't get it to work properly. In the below screenshot the left-hand side of the checkbox should line up with "Headline", but it doesn't.

I feel like I've just been trying the same things over and over, so I figured I would take a bit of a break from trying to figure this out and see if someone here might have some insight. I'm sure it's an easy solution, but for some reason it's completely eluding me.

**EDIT:** Apparently one of the sites I was using to get this working had incorrect information. The `<div class="checkbox">` is completely unnecessary and is what was causing the alignment issue. After removing this div everything started working properly.

[image]

HTML:

```
<h3>Headline</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="square-red" name="test_checkbox" value="1" checked>Checkbox text
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
/* iCheck plugin Square skin, red
----------------------------------- */
.icheckbox_square-red,
.iradio_square-red {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    background: url(red.png) no-repeat;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.icheckbox_square-red {
    background-position: 0 0;
}
    .icheckbox_square-red.hover {
        background-position: -24px 0;
    }
    .icheckbox_square-red.checked {
        background-position: -48px 0;
    }
    .icheckbox_square-red.disabled {
        background-position: -72px 0;
        cursor: default;
    }
    .icheckbox_square-red.checked.disabled {
        background-position: -96px 0;
    }

.iradio_square-red {
    background-position: -120px 0;
}
    .iradio_square-red.hover {
        background-position: -144px 0;
    }
    .iradio_square-red.checked {
        background-position: -168px 0;
    }
    .iradio_square-red.disabled {
        background-position: -192px 0;
        cursor: default;
    }
    .iradio_square-red.checked.disabled {
        background-position: -216px 0;
    }

/* Retina support */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (-moz-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5),
       only screen and (-o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 3/2),
       only screen and (min-device-pixel-ratio: 1.5) {
    .icheckbox_square-red,
    .iradio_square-red {
        background-image: url(red@2x.png);
        -webkit-background-size: 240px 24px;
        background-size: 240px 24px;
    }
}
```

JS:

```
//Red color scheme for iCheck
$('input[type="checkbox"].square-red, input[type="radio"].square-red').iCheck({
  checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-red',
  radioClass: 'iradio_square-red'
});
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your problem. Your code looks ok. Your problem comes probably from something else.

Comment: @smdsgn It turns out that one of the sites I was using as a reference had this setup wrong and the `<div class="checkbox">` is what was causing the issue. Things started working properly once this was removed.